# Reduce disc space of SpringBoot executable jar Angular App

Tags: java, angular, maven, spring-boot

The Maven project: SpringBoot has one SpringBoot start up class.  Angular website in the 'resouces/public' folder.

The app starts up and serves the index.html from the public folder.

I want to reduce the size of the spring boot app.  I've done the trimming of the Angular App.

What options do I have in SpringBoot to only run a static website? Any boiler plate code I can exclude?

Note: This is a Maven project.

Comment: what do you use to build your project? maven?

Comment: Yes, it is a Maven project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to save ~13MB in executable JAR

- SpringBoot is about 14MB without hibernate (5MB)
- Angular, removing the FONTS folder saved me ~8MB

What I did was run `mvn dependency:tree`

Then I looked through the list and removed Hibernate by updating the pom with the exclusion:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot-version}</version>
                  <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                  </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
```

Dependency Tree

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.24:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO]    +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO]    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.7.RELEASE:test
```

Comment: nice, that's where i was going with my comment.  glad to see you found a solution.